# How to convert .inp (InPage Urdu) files to PDF

Tags: pdf, converters, file-extension

If you have an InPage Urdu file and you want to convert it to a pdf file for viewing then what  should you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many ways to achieve this task. The one which I found out to be most easy is described below:

You need MS Word or Some other PDF Maker that can convert multiple images into a single PDF.

I used MS Word.

First, Open the file in InPage, go to File, Export Page. From this menu you can export all the pages as images and then drag drop these images to MS Word and Save as PDF

Alternatively you can select Print option from File menu in InPage and send it to Adobe PDF if you have it installed.